# Using \newtheorem with the standalone document class

Tags: theorems, standalone, png, newtheorem

Is it possible to create a small file containing a theorem? (possibly using the standalone document class)
Using the following code with the standalone fails:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
...
\begin{document}
    \begin{theorem}
        ...
    \end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You’ve already got a good answer, but sometimes, putting a `minipage` environment within the `standalone` works.

Answer (score 2):

When using list environments (such as theorem environments) in a `standalone` document, you can use the `varwidth` option. The following example compiles correctly.

[image]

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
    \begin{theorem}
    A theorem.
    \end{theorem}
\end{document}
```